# How to create a new Solr server URL

Tags: 7, search

I am using Tomcat with Apache Solr to search the content on my site.

For testing purposes, I use http://localhost:8080/solr to connect to the Solr server, but I would like to change this to http://development.site:8080/solr.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your Solr server from /admin/config/search/search_api/server/apache_solr/edit.

Comment: That wont work unless he changes the configuration of Solr to listen on the new domain name 1st, that only alters where Drupal sends the search requests.
@Slasengger you want to look in the Solr configuration XML files, for example $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml and change localhost to yoursite.dev. I'm not 100% which XML configuration file you need, as  I don't have Solr installed, and I don't know if you're using Tomcat, Jetty, or Apache with a Java connector.